# Iterator over std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Element>>

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, iterator

I have a class storing some data in unordered_map. Let us assume that the class looks as follows:

```
class Container {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Element>> map;
};
```

And for convenience, I would like to iterate over the contents of my Container using range-for-loop, so that I would get all the `Elements` in nested vectors.

```
for (const Element& e : Container(...)) {
    magic(e);
}
```

To do this I need to implement iterator, that would iterate over the elements of nested vectors. I tried to do it myself, but ended up with such a malfunctioning monstrosity, that I don't even dare to put it here. I just provide a [link](http://codepad.org/6z8sXQLs) to the code I wrote, but it's just terrible and it doesn't work properly because I was unable to implement `end` correctly.

So my question is, can it be done in some elegant manner? Or at least correctly? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you are in the right track, but there are a few rough edges in your code. Anyway, it is probably a better question for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as you do not have any specific question, just "how can I improve my code?".

Comment: On the right track? Well perhaps I can post the code on codereview, but to me the code looks just ridiculous. It seemed to me quite elementary and it was very unpleasant to find it both difficult and not solved anywhere else.

Comment: Well, I didn't check all your code. You need two iterator members to track the position (the pointer to the map is not needed except for assertions). Maybe some of your dancing with iterators is unnecesary, though.

Comment: I mean. To advance the iterator: first advance the vector iterator, if it reaches the end of its vector, advance the map iterator and reset the vector iterator to the beginning of the next one, unless it is empty, of course.

Comment: I think you may be missing after `++m_vec_it;` something like `if (m_vec_it != vec_end()) return;`.

Comment: That were my thoughts. But the problem is with controlling the end. Since iterators don't have any default uninitialized value, I would need to obtain the end of last vector in the map. But I don't think, that I am able to do that without iterating through the whole map.

Comment: Ah, that is a well known problem with C++ iterators. I think that in C++17 there was some proposal to address that. For now you could simply add the special case in `operator==()`: `if (lhs.m_map_it == rhs.m_map_it && lhs.m_map_it == m_map->cend()) return true;`. And implement `operator!=()` negating the `==`.

Comment: I mean, your `end` iterator should **not** be your `map_it` pointing to the last vector and your `vec_it` pointing to `vec_cend`. It should be your `map_it` pointing to `m_map->cend()` and your `vec_it` pointing nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick I learned a long time ago to convert a normal function into a kind of generator (or coroutine, or whatever it is called these days).

Imagine that C++ had the `yield` keyword, like Python or C#. Then doing the iteration would be simple:

```
void shift()
{
    for (auto mapIt = bag->begin(); mapIt != bat->end(); ++mapIt)
    {   
        for (auto vecIt = mapIt->second.begin(); vecIt != mapIt->second.end(); ++vecIt)
        {   
            yield *vecIt; //Alas, C++ cannot yield!
        }
    }
}
```

The transformation to a proper C++ function can be done semi-automatically, following these easy steps:

1-Move all local variables to the top of the function:

```
void shift()
{
    mapIt_t mapIt; //assume the proper typedefs somewhere
    vecIt_t vecIt;

    for (mapIt = bag->begin(); mapIt != bat->end(); ++mapIt)
    {   
        for (vecIt = mapIt->second.begin(); vecIt != mapIt->second.end(); ++vecIt)
        {   
            yield *vecIt; //Alas, C++ cannot yield!
        }
    }
}
```

2-Transform the local variables into member variables. Add a `int m_state;` member variable, initialized to `0`.

```
mapIt_t m_mapIt;
vecIt_t m_vecIt;
int m_state = 0;
void shift()
{

    for (m_mapIt = bag->begin(); m_mapIt != bat->end(); ++m_mapIt)
    {   
        for (m_vecIt = m_mapIt->second.begin(); m_vecIt != m_mapIt->second.end(); ++m_vecIt)
        {   
            yield *m_vecIt; //Alas, C++ cannot yield!
        }
    }
}
```

3-Wrap the function in a `switch (m_state)` statement. Put a `case 0:` at the beginning:

```
mapIt_t m_mapIt;
vecIt_t m_vecIt;
int m_state = 0;
void shift()
{switch (m_state) { case 0: //behold my fancy indentation!

    for (m_mapIt = bag->begin(); m_mapIt != bat->end(); ++m_mapIt)
    {   
        for (m_vecIt = m_mapIt->second.begin(); m_vecIt != m_mapIt->second.end(); ++m_vecIt)
        {   
            yield *m_vecIt; //Alas, C++ cannot yield!
        }
    }

}}
```

4-Replace each `yield` with the following statements: `m_state = N; return; case N:;`, being `N` a different integer for each place used. Add `m_state = -1; return; case -1:;` at the end of the function. Use a macro if you feel it is worth it.

```
mapIt_t m_mapIt;
vecIt_t m_vecIt;
int m_state = 0;
void shift()
{switch (m_state) { case 0: //behold my fancy indentation!

    for (m_mapIt = bag->begin(); m_mapIt != bat->end(); ++m_mapIt)
    {   
        for (m_vecIt = m_mapIt->second.begin(); m_vecIt != m_mapIt->second.end(); ++m_vecIt)
        {   
            m_state = 1; return; case 1:;
        }
    }
    m_state = -1; return; case -1:;
}}
```

5-Done! You can make the container as complex as you want: if you can write a function that does the full iteration, you will be able to convert it into an iterator class.

---

With all that in mind I have written the following sample code, that seems to work fine.

```
class Bag
{
public:
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string> > container_t;
    container_t cnt;
};

class BagIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, std::string>
{
public:
    friend BagIterator begin(const Bag &bag);
    friend BagIterator end(const Bag &bag);

    BagIterator()
    {
        m_bag = NULL;
        m_state = -1;
    }

    const value_type &operator*() const
    {
        return *m_vecIt;
    }
    BagIterator &operator++()
    {
        shift();
        return *this;
    }
    BagIterator operator++(int)
    {
        BagIterator tmp = *this;
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }
    bool operator==(const BagIterator &r) const
    {
        if (m_state != r.m_state)
            return false;
        if (m_state == -1)
            return true;
        return m_bag == r.m_bag && m_mapIt == r.m_mapIt && m_vecIt == r.m_vecIt;
    }
    bool operator!=(const BagIterator &r) const
    {
        return !operator==(r);
    }
private:
    typedef Bag::container_t::const_iterator mapIt_t;
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator vecIt_t;
    const Bag *m_bag;
    mapIt_t m_mapIt;
    vecIt_t m_vecIt;
    int m_state;

    void shift()
    {switch (m_state) { case 0:
        for (m_mapIt = m_bag->cnt.begin(); m_mapIt != m_bag->cnt.end(); ++m_mapIt)
        {
            for (m_vecIt = m_mapIt->second.begin(); m_vecIt != m_mapIt->second.end(); ++m_vecIt)
            {
                m_state = 1; return; case 1:;
            }
        }
        m_state = -1; return; case -1:;
    }}
};

BagIterator begin(const Bag &bag)
{
    BagIterator res;
    res.m_bag = &bag;
    res.m_state = 0;
    res.shift();
    return res;
}
BagIterator end(const Bag &bag)
{
    BagIterator res;
    res.m_bag = &bag;
    return res;
}
```

A few comments:

- Note how I derived the custom iterator from `std::iterator` so that the standard library will know how it works.
- Note also how I implemented the `operator==()`. First it checks that the state is the same, then if both are `end()` (`m_state==-1`), and finally if both point to the same element.